# Check Boolean value in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I want to return a boolean value to check if the String contains any 'value' or not after getting data from database.
It should return true if it contains anything else false.

```
JSONObject context = memory.getContext(senderId, sessionId);
```

If this context contains any value from db, it should return true when i sysout it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I am using org.json.simple library

Comment: Check for not `empty` and `null` and return true else return false

Comment: First, which library are you using? Is that object yours?

After that, check `size` or `length` method, it should be one.

Comment: @Shirkam i edited the question. I am using org.json.simple library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if the context is `null` or not and return if `size()` is grater than `0`.

```
...
JSONObject context = memory.getContext(senderId, sessionId);

return context != null && context.size() > 0;
```

Comment: It can never be less than 2.

Comment: If we're talking about `org.json.JSONObject` here then its `toString()` will return `"{}"` if there is no actual content, in which case `context.toString().length() > 0` will return true when there is no actual content.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it be `size()` instead of `length()` @glitch ?

Comment: My answer was based on the assumption that we were talking about `org.json.JSONObject`, the OP later updated his question to state that the JSONObject at play here is `org.json.simple.JSONObject`. For `org.json.simple.JSONObject` the correct answer is `.size()`. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `JSONObject` is `org.json.simple.JSONObject` its `size` method will allow you to determine whether it has any content, for example:

```
return context != null && context.size() > 0;
```

Comment: It should be `context.size()`

Comment: Yep, now that the OP's question has been updated to to make clear that the JSONObject at play here is `org.json.simple.JSONObject` rather than `org.json.JSONObject` I have updated my answer. Thanks :)